# Mojang API authentication token. Discord.js

Tags: node.js, axios, get, discord.js

So I am trying to get something from Mojang API I'm trying to get if a certain name is available. But I cant figure out how I am supposed to get the authentication token to send the request. Can someone explain how do I get the token to send the request. And Everything That I have tried hasnt worked. The Furthest I have gotten is a 401 error.
I tried axios

```
            axios({
                headers: { Authorization: '<api key>'},
                url: '/minecraft/profile/name/userbruh/available',
                method: 'get'
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {

                  console.log(error);
              });
```

It didnt work
I tried normal node HTTP requests

```
            const options = {
              hostname: 'api.minecraftservices.com/minecraft/profile/name/userbruh/available',
              path: '/minecraft/profile/name/userbruh/available',
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
                'Authorization': '<api-key>'
              }
            }
            
            const req = https.request(options, res => {
              console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
            
              res.on('data', d => {
                process.stdout.write(d)
              })
            })
            
            req.on('error', error => {
              console.error(error)
            })
            
            req.end()
```

That didnt work either and I just cant find out what im supposed to do. Oh I got the auth token from the bearer token in from my account from the minecraft.net page
Someone please help me try to get this Mojang Bearer token

Comment: At least show us your code, what you ave tried so far !

Comment: I added the code that i tried.

Comment: Bruh remove the authorization key, now. replace it with "<api key> on the question before someones steals it and uses it

Comment: ok there i removed it

Comment: Okay ! Try using https://rapidapi.com/blog/minecraft-api-with-python-php-ruby-javascript-examples/

Comment: It kind of works.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: You need to follow one of the auth flows below to attain the token for that request.**

When Microsoft bought Minecraft, they overhauled the authentication steps & started migrating Minecraft account to Microsoft ones. Since that's still an ongoing process so there's two auth flows that exist at the moment. Thankfully, they're very well documented:

- for older Minecraft accounts, steps are here: https://wiki.vg/Authentication
- for newer, post migration accounts, they're here: https://wiki.vg/Microsoft_Authentication_Scheme

The newer is naturally much more obtuse and a pain to implement, but there are reference implementations in various languages at the bottom of that page. Happy coding!